# hidden space in the middle of scraped text

Tags: php, html, web-scraping

im doing some data scraping ... basically i'm getting some webpage using curl , extract the data and check my database to see if they exist in my db .

so i was been looking for `Beijing Guoan (Chn)` in a webpage source code and i couldn't find it , but it was there and i could see it in the browser .

```
  $result = phpQuery::newDocument( file_get_contents('www.site.com/page'), 'text/html'); 

  foreach($result->find('td.table-participant-teams') as $t )
  {
     list( $host , $guest ) = explode( ' - ' ,  pq($t)->text());

     echo $host.' == Beijing Guoan (Chn) ==> '; 
     echo $host   == 'Beijing Guoan (Chn)' ? ' found it ' : ' false ';
  }
```

result :

```
Beijing Guoan (Chn) == Beijing Guoan (Chn) ==> false
```

i did a `strlen($host)` and i found `$host` was 20 charchter while `Beijing Guoan (Chn)` has 19 .... basically there is hidden charachter in `$host`

so i've added

```
for($i = 0 ; $i < strlen($host) ; $i++)
{
    echo $i.' - '.$host[$i];
    echo '<br />';
}
```

and i got

```
0 - B
1 - e
2 - i
3 - j
4 - i
5 - n
6 - g
7 -
8 - G
9 - u
10 - o
11 - a
12 - n
13 -
14 -
15 - (
16 - C
17 - h
18 - n
19 - )
```

as you can see in 13,14 i got 2 spaces  , but when i print out $host i only have 1 ! and that's what cuzing all the trouble

---

so whay there is a extra space in my $host but it wont show when i print it out on the screen and how can i get rid of it ?

please note that i don't want to just remove that extra space from this specific string , there might be other cases with different char-length , iwant a solution that works on all of them

Comment: It's to be expected. When rendering HTML, line breaks (`\n`), consecutive spaces, etc... are all ignored and not rendered. Your browser basically **LIES** to you, as part of the rendering process.

Comment: Try to remove all white space inside your code to see if some causes that extra space.

Comment: Can remove all the white space (and maybe convert all characters to lower) for just the comparison?

Comment: What is it **exactly** you want to do? Change all multiple white space to single white space?

Comment: Is this a typo `echo $host.' == Beijing Guoan (Chn) ==> ';`

Comment: @mdesdev i did remove consecutive spaces and it worked , `str_replace('  ' ,' ' , $host)`  , and no i just wrote this part in here but it's not a typo

Comment: @grebneke i want to be able to check my database for this string  , but it will fail all the time becuz of these hidden characters ... basically i want my variable to contain exactly what it shows when i print it out

Comment: "exactly what it shows when I print it out" - does that mean printing in the browser (html) or printing to an actual terminal or file? @ZubaiR has given an example of how to squash multiple whitespace, which is more or less what the browser does. See my comment there for suggestion of `/\s+/`. If that's not what you need, please clarify

Comment: @grebneke browser , as i said to ZubaiR this is pretty good but there is a slight chance of error ... i want to get rid of invisible spaces  , consecutive  or not

Comment: @max You fail to explain exactly what you mean by 'invisible spaces' - **where** are they invisible - in the browser? In that case ZubaiR's answer is good but use `/\s+/`.

Comment: @grebneke you probably didn't see it , but i did said `browser` in my last comment

Comment: @max, right you did, I missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML renders multiple consecutive space as one. If you view the source you will see the actual data.

To replace multiple consecutive white space you can use the following

```
echo preg_replace('/ +/', ' ', 'he   llo      test');
```

Comment: Or use `/\s+/` to also squash tabs and newlines into single space character

Comment: thanks this would be my last option , it's not very likely but there might be a strings with actual consecutive space